# BAT files that type words

Tags: batch-file

I need to type the same words repeatedly is there a way that i can have  a bat file loop and type it repeatedly through my keyboard? I know loops are :loop goto loop but as for the rest im clueless.

Comment: Do you need to type it repeatedly to the screen or to a file?

Comment: You could also use powershell batch with the sendkeys command but you'd have to be on Vista and above - powershell needs .net framework to be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files can only operate within the confines of the operating system.  You want to add words within an app.  This can be done with Windows Scripting (or even using VBA via Excel or Access), but not with a BAT file.

Answer (score 0):

This is to type to the screen

```
:loop
echo whatever
goto :loop
```

Or

```
for /L %%a in (1,0,1) do (echo whatever)
```

for writing to a file you just add >>filename.txt to the end of whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send the words to an application, like Notepad?

```
' Open notepad 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad", 9

' Give Notepad time to load
WScript.Sleep 500 

Do
   'type in Hello World
   WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!"
   WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Loop Until 1=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a batch file but it allows you to repeat strings and paragraphs of text very easily.

`Autohotkey` is a tool that uses a text file and it can include lines like this:

```
::.c::[code]echo Here is my code[/code]

::.b::[b]This is Bold[/b]

::address1::
send Peter PumpkinEater{enter}
send 213 The Patch{enter}
send Fairyland{enter}
return
```

and when you type `.c` and space then it will print `[code]echo Here is my code[/code]` to the `text editor` or `website forum` or `program` you are using at the time.

When you type `.b` and space it will print `[b]This is Bold[/b]`
and when you type `address1` and space it will type this:

Peter PumpkinEater
213 The Patch
Fairyland

It is far more powerful than just the `hotstrings` that I have outlined and is a wonderful tool.